# Calling the method through the static Instance of the class

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have Created The an Interface Named As ICountry

```
public  interface ICountry
    {
        List<CountryProperty> GetAllCountry();
        List< CountryProperty> GetCountryById(int countryid);

    }
```

Then after i had created the an Abstract class Named as CountryProvider  in which i had implemented the Method of the ICountry Interface  like this

```
public abstract   class CountryProvider:ICountry
  {

      public static CountryProvider Instance
      {
          get
          {
              return new Country();
          }
      }


      public abstract List<CountryProperty> GetAllCountry();


      public abstract List<CountryProperty> GetCountryById(int countryid);

    }
```

Then After i had created the a simple class named as Country and inherit the class CountryProvider and Override the abstract  method

```
public   class Country: CountryProvider 
  {
      private DbWrapper _objDataWrapper;
      private DataSet _dataSet;


      public override List<CountryProperty> GetAllCountry()
      {   _dataSet=new DataSet();
          _objDataWrapper = new DbWrapper(Common.CnnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
          var objCountryList = new List<CountryProperty>();
          try
          {
             _dataSet=_objDataWrapper.ExecuteDataSet("Aj_Proc_GetCountryList");
              objCountryList = BindCountryObject(_dataSet.Tables[0]);

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

          }
          return objCountryList;
      }

      public override List<CountryProperty> GetCountryById(int countryid)
      {
          _dataSet = new DataSet();
          _objDataWrapper = new DbWrapper(Common.CnnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
          var objCountryList = new List<CountryProperty>();
          try
          {
              _objDataWrapper.AddParameter("@CountryId", countryid);
              _dataSet = _objDataWrapper.ExecuteDataSet("Aj_Proc_GetCountryList");
              objCountryList = BindCountryObject(_dataSet.Tables[0]);

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              var err = ex.Message;

          }
          return objCountryList;
      }

      private List <CountryProperty> BindCountryObject(DataTable dataTable )
      {
          if (dataTable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dataTable");
          var objCountryList = new List<CountryProperty>();


        try
          {
              if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0 )
              {

                  for(var j=0;j<dataTable.Rows.Count;j++)
                  {
                      var objCountry = new CountryProperty
                                           {
                                               CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[j]["AjCountryId"]),
                                               CountryCode = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[j]["AjCountryCode"]),
                                               CountryName = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[j]["AjCountryName"])
                                           };
                      objCountryList.Add(objCountry);
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {


          }
          return objCountryList;
      }
  }
```

Then after i am calling the method like this

```
   var data = CountryProvider.Instance.GetAllCountry();
```

My Question is that it is tight approach to follow or not

Comment: Do you want a single object of Country across application?

Comment: Yes i want the single object of the country though out the application also let me know the scenario where i have to use  or where i have to not use this pattern

Comment: do you need that interface,you are making those two methods abstract anyway in the abstract class

Comment: Whether or not you're going in the right direction depends on where you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Singleton Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) in case you want the single instance across application -

```
private static Country country;
public static CountryProvider Instance
{
   get
   {
      if(country == null)
      {
         country = new Country();
      }
      return country;
   }
}
```

And you `don't need an abstract class` since everytime you wanted to return the intance of a Country. So, Country class should implement the interface directly since other two methods are abstract anyway which you are overriding in class Country.